# Save RadioButtons and CheckListBox in same structure

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a task: to write some test, but some questions have radio buttons as answers, and some has checklistbox as answers. I come to think of this one(how to save answers with radiobuttons): `Dictionary<RadioButton, bool> answers = new Dictionary<RadioButton, bool>();` . I am saving every question in such structure:

```
class Question
    {
        public Question(Label lab,  Dictionary<RadioButton, bool> ans)
        {
            text = lab;
            answers = ans;
            isAnswered = false;
        }
        public Label text { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<RadioButton, bool> answers { get; set; }// = new Dictionary<RadioButton, bool>();
        public bool isAnswered;

    }
```

But this saves only radiobuttons. How to do it, but when some objects must save `CheckedListBox`, instead of `RadioButton`s

Answer (score 0):

One of options is using Control class in your dictionary which is base class for both CheckedListBox and RadioButton. Although I doubt that you need a reference to real control, it makes a sense to save KeyValuePair instead, where key is name of radio button or checkbox item and value is the state. Finally, yet another option is to maintain checked/selected items only whereas all others consider to be unchecked